# How to change data rate of a Phidget Sensor?

Tags: java, sensors

So im working on Phidget sensor project in Java. The idea is to send the values of the sensors to a database.

Inside the onSensorChanged method I have a uploadToServer method call. The issue with that is when using a fast data rate and I turn a dial, or move a slider, the onSensorChanged method gets triggered almost instantly resulting in the uploadToServer method triggered 10-20 times per dial turn.

I've tried slowing down the data rate to 1000ms, but it still prints multiple values, the value just after moving, then after the data rate length.

```
    interfacephid.setDataRate(0, 1000);
```

So for example if I start at sensor value of 0, and rapidly move the dial its full rotation. Then I get two readings, one around the 100 area and then the final resting place 999. Ideally i'd prefer just to print the final position.

I have no idea why I get the first reading. The data rate is 1000ms, so in theory if I rapidly move the slider, the onSensorChanged method should only trigger after 1 second, resulting in 1 value being sent to the server.

I've got a feeling I might have to implement a separate work around for this decreasing the data rate isn't doing the job.

Here is my onSensorChanged method, nothing unusual here:

```
public void sensorChanged(SensorChangeEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Slider value is "+arg0.getValue());
    uploadSensorValue("sliderValue",sensorValue);
}
```

Console output is similar to this (usually more):

```
Slider value is 878
Slider value is 721
Slider value is 513
Slider value is 328
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a sensorChangeTrigger value as well as the datarate?  Those two parameters somewhat override one another.  If you have a change trigger set it will fire an event every time the input changes by that much regardless of the datarate (depending on the order you set the parameters in your code).  This sounds like what is happening to you, you should only set the datarate or the change trigger in your code, it is not necessary to set both.